# Can you combine multivalue fields to form a consolidated Splunk alert?

Tags: splunk

I have a Splunk search which returns several logs of the same exception, one for each ID number (from a batch process). I have no problem extracting the field from the log with reg-ex and can build a single alert for each ID number easily.

```
Slack Message: "Reference number $result.extractedField$ has failed processing."
```

Since the error happens in batches, sending out an alert for every reference ID that failed would clutter up my Slack channel very quickly. Is it possible to collect all of the extracted fields and set the alert to send only one message? Like this...

```
Slack Message: "Reference numbers $result.listOfExtractedFields$ have failed to process."
```

Comment: If you have a field called "listOfExtractedFields" in your query then that should work.  Please share your search query so I help you better.

Comment: @RichG This is a Splunk search, so I'm not entirely sure how to form a list within the search. But, the search string is...`index=the_index_im_searching "the class where the error occurs" "the exception I'm looking for"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have a consolidated alert you need consolidated search results.  Do that like this:

```
index=the_index_youre_searching "the class where the error occurs" "the exception you're looking for" 
| stats values(*) as * by referenceID
```

Be sure to select the "Once" Trigger Condition in the alert setup.

Comment: This works perfectly inside the web interface, but in the error report I'm sending via email I only get one of the referenceIDs printed. This is the message I'm sending `Invoice Keys: $result.uniqueDuplicateInvoiceNumber$ failed to post, causing a duplicate invoice error.`

Comment: Your answer definitely started me down the right path!  mvcombine and nomv is what ended up working.